# For loop and if in puts function - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to use for loop and if condition in creating a file using `File.open` and `puts` function. My code is

```
I want to write these entries only if it is not null. How to do it?

Edit: Full code is
```

require 'fileutils'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

data = JSON.parse('data')

array = data
if array &.any?

drafts_dir = File.expand_path('../drats', **dir**)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(drafts_dir)

array.each do |entry|

```
File.open(File.join(drafts_dir, "#{entry['twitter']}.md"), 'wb') do |draft|
keys = 1.upto(6).map { |i| "key_#{i}" }

values = keys.map { |k| "<img src='#{entry['image']} alt='image'>" if entry['image']}
# you can also do values = entry.values_at(*keys)

str = values.reject do |val|
  val.nil? || val.length == 0 
end.join("\n")

draft.puts str  
end
```

end
end

```
I need the the file `mark.md` as
```

https://somesite.com/image.png' alt='image'>
https://twitter.com/mark'>mark

```
and `kevin.md` likewise.
```

Comment: "You can see some values are null." – I don't see any null values in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can build the string from an array, rejecting the null values:

```
keys = 1.upto(6).map { |i| "key_#{i}" }

values = keys.map { |k| entry[k] }
# you can also do values = entry.values_at(*keys)

str = values.reject do |val|
  val.nil? || val.length == 0 
end.join("\n")

draft.puts str
```

---

*update* in response to your changed question. Do this:

```
array.each do |entry|
  File.open(File.join(drafts_dir, "#{entry['twitter']}.md"), 'wb') do |draft| 
    next unless ['image', 'twitter'].all? { |k| entry[k]&.length > 1 }
    str = [
      "<img src='#{entry['image']} alt='image'>",
      "<a href='https://twitter.com/#{entry['twitter']}'>#{entry['twitter']}</a>"
    ].join("\n")
    draft.puts str  
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my question. Can you please review it?

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar just replace your `draft.puts` line with the first snippet in my answer

Comment: replace the `values=` line ...`values = keys.map { |k| "<a href="www.somesite.com">#{entry[k]}</a>\n\n" if entry[k]}`

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar Can you please edit your question to show the actual input and expected output? It would have been easier if you just did this in the first place.

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar ok this is more simple now. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar it's because the `twitter` key is empty for mark. With all due respect, this seems like a homework question, and please in the future always include the full, actual requirements in your question to avoid this back-and-forth

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, your `entry` is hash.

```
final_string = ''
entry.each_value { |value| final_string << "#{value}\n" }
puts final_string
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my question. Can you please review it?

Comment: @MonsoonMalabar i don't understand. `You can see some values are null.` ... no, i don't see that

Comment: @maxpleaner `data = JSON.parse('[{"key1":"value","key2":"","key3":"value","key4":"","key5":"value"}, {"key1":"value","key2":"","key3":"value","key4":"","key5":"value"}]')`. Here value for key2, key4 in first set and second is null

Comment: It's actually not null, it's just an empty string. Instead of `compact` use `reject { |val| val.length == 0 }` or if you're using active support / rails you can use `reject(&:blank?)`